# mvvm light simpleIoc constructor injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mvvm-light, simpleioc

i want to inject a list to my viewmodel constructor with the ServiceLocator

my viewmodel:

```
public class ShowEmployeeViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private IList<IEmployee> _empl;

    public ShowEmployeeViewModel(IList<IEmployee> emp)
    {

        this._empl = emp;

        _empl.Add(new Employee() { empName = "foo", enpFunction = "bar" });
    }
}
```

my servicelocator:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{

    public ViewModelLocator()
    {

        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        //register the interface against the class

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register < IList < IEmployee >, List <Employee>>();


        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ShowEmployeeViewModel>();

    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }
    public ShowEmployeeViewModel ShowEmployee
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ShowEmployeeViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

when i run this code i got an error:
"Cannot register: Multiple constructors found in List`1 but none marked with PreferredConstructor."
PS: i only got this error when i try to registre a list "IList" but when i register my interface like this:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register < IEmployee , Employee >();
```

it works fine, any idea how to register a list?
thanks in advance

Comment: You are mixing things up here. A DI Container (and DI in general) is not meant to build up DTOs and entities; its meant to build up graphs of application components, i.e. the classes that contain that application's behavior. `ShowEmployeeViewModel` is a DTO and `IEmployee` is an entity. Do not register them in your container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't map the `IList` interface, use a factory for your `ShowEmployeeViewModel` class:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register(() => new ShowEmployeeViewModel(new List<IEmployee>()));
```

Comment: it works, but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the Dependency Injection, how can i register a type against its interface? thanks

Comment: You don't map a generic list against a specific type. This makes no sense since you want to be able to use a generic list for many different types. You could map a view model interface, e.g. IShowViewModel, against a concrete view model type though but that's another story and since your ShowEmployeeViewModel class doesn't even implement an interface it is not applicable here.